# Peak Hours for Tweeting

Tags: time-series, arima

I am trying to figure out the peak hours during a 24 hour period for my companies twitter account.  We are trying to find the sweet spot to optimize our interactions 
(RT+Replies+Favorites).

I have the data broken out into the hour it was tweeted, number of interactions, and number of tweets that were sent out during that time.  This is for the past 9 months.  I am not sure what the best way to analyze this would be I saw a few threads that mentioned ARIMA, but I must admit I am not much of a statistician.  However I am familiar with some basic statistical methods and am proficient in excel and do some work in VBA.  Any advice would be appreciated.

-Aidan

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to construct a model which relates the variables in an effective way. Please specify what your are trying to predict and specifically what causal variables you think are important. Since this is time series data it may be important to capture/account for hourly variation, daily variation ,weekly variation, monthly variation , holiday effects, level shifts , trends ,. etc. The approach is generally called ARMAX or Dynamic Regression or Transfer Function Analysis . Care must be taken to identify and isolate the effects on anomalies. If you wish to post your data via Dropbox or any other method please do so and I will try and help you using AUTOBOX a piece of time series software that I have helped develop. If the results are good you can use that package or any other package that performs the required analysis in a similar way.

Comment: Why would anyone reasonably expect this model to apply to the responses to tweets? Sure, there might be some relationship between those responses and time of day or duration since some relevant event--but why would those responses exhibit any kind of stationary structure or even any kind of temporal correlation whatsoever?  This post is so similar to several hundred nearly identical previous posts of yours that one is led to infer you are not giving any consideration to the question, but only reproducing your standard post for advertising purposes.

Comment: I have studied social data like this and been able to form reasonable models. I was simply stating what software he could use and making it very transparent that I was not hiding anything . You had previously (correctly) guided me to providing full disclosure regarding the tools being used. I gave specific references to methodology and can only suggest that good analysis would reveal the structure ( if any ! ). There is nothing I can specifically about tweets other that if it is time series then it is possible to empirically construct appropriate lag models.

Comment: Since time series is all that I know, it is all that I can talk about. All of this "advertising" has lead to zero sales which was never the objective but more knowledgeable posters.

Comment: Im trying to forecast the optimal time of day to send out tweets.  I think the ARMAX analysis may involve more than I am capable of.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the data as it is sensitive, but it consists of the frequency, a time range for example 3-4PM and the interactions received.  

whuber what type of analysis would you recommend to try and find peak hours for our twitter account?  There are several services like twiteroid or buffer that sell subscriptions and provide this type of analysis.  I thought this is something I could do on my own even with my limited statistics knowledge.

Comment: Since you have time series data, simple frequency distribution analysis might be useless and you may have no recourse but to deal with this problem using time series methods IMHO. The optimal time of the day may differ depend on what day-of-the-week or possibly other variables. If you can not share the actual data you might code it and deliver scaled data which can then be used to teach you as to what you need to do.