# Choosing the right ARIMA model in MATLAB

Tags: forecasting, model-selection, econometrics, arima, seasonality

I have a problem regarding choosing the right model for historical data that I need to forecast. When drawing the ACF and PACf, a clear seasonality appears at lag 24 as you can see in the figure:
[image: ACF and PACF]

I used the model: "ExU_1_7" is the historical data for 7 days

```
model= arima('Constant',0,'D',0,'Seasonality',24,...
'ARLags',[1],'SARLags',[23,24])   
    fit = estimate(model,(ExU_1_7));
    res = infer(fit,(ExU_1_7));
    [yF] = forecast(fit,24,'Y0',(ExU_1_7));
```

Is this suitable? I want also to ask about the presample data concept and how to choose the right one "Y0 or XF or Xo etc".

Comment: Did you try ARMA(24,24) - aka ARIMA(24,0,24)?

Answer (score 1):

if you have hourly data you might want to build a mixed frequency model which will embody daily patterns perhaps due to holiday events or other user specified causal variables. You might want to look at [Peak Hours for Tweeting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121175/peak-hours-for-tweeting/121219#121219)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to stick with ARIMA since I'm not a forecasting guy...I need to do forecasting for my thesis and I find it confusing to choose the right model by looking at ACF and PACF....can you help me to understand these figures???

Comment: when you have hourly data there is often seasonal arima structure at lag 7 thus what you night di is to build 24 arima  models ...one for each hour ...